# Flutter How do I use custom paint to draw smoothly according to speed?

Tags: flutter, canvas

As shown in the picture below, I want it to be drawn smoothly like a signature depending on the drawing speed (touch pressure?).

[image]

What should I do for this?
There are some packages in Flutter Dev, but I'm going to add more functions than that, so I'm going to try to implement them myself if possible.

This is a code for a simple drawing that I've used.

```
final paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      ..strokeWidth = width; 

class Sketcher extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Shape> shapes;

  Sketcher(this.shapes) : super();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.polygon, points, paint);

    @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
  }
```

I want to implement this using a `GestureDetector` and `CustomPaint`.

Can I see an example about this?

Comment: what device are you using? have you read https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ForcePressGestureRecognizer-class.html?

Comment: Use an Android, IOS tablet. I saw the document, but I didn't understand it well yet.